# Mysql update with an incremental value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want make an update in one request (if possible) for make less mysql request..

I've a table  with differents columns and a column "order" and I want change the value in the "order"

I can make a loop foreach in PHP, but each loop is a request like this:

```
 $i = 1;
 foreach($tables as $table){
    $sql = 'UPDATE `table` SET `order` = '$i' WHERE `id` ='.$table['id'].';';
    $i++;
 }
```

Does it possible to make only one request ?

I've find this but it don't work

```
SET @pos := 0;
$sql ='UPDATE table SET order = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 );';
```

Or I don't know how to make it work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I've understand that's not possible directly with MySQL query. So I'll make a loop for update each row, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This approach can solve your problem with a single query, but it will be tedious if we have more records

Let us have a table named order_details

```
CREATE TABLE `order_details` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
)

Select * from order_details    

order_id order_description order_value
1        a                 11
2        b                 12
3        c                 13
```

Now updating multiple rows in a single query

```
UPDATE test.order_details
SET order_value = CASE order_id
WHEN 1 THEN 21
WHEN 2 THEN 22
WHEN 3 THEN 23
END WHERE order_id IN (1,2,3)
```

You can verify it by executing a select query

```
Select * from order_details    

order_id order_description order_value
1        a                 21
2        b                 22
3        c                 23
```

Comment: How were you planning on writing that above update statement if there are 1.8 Million rows in the table?

Comment: For sure, this way is good for fews rows to change. In my case, it's between 30 to 800 each time

Comment: @Amazone - In the case of records between 30 to 800 generate the query using a foreach loop, and execute it. Its all about whether we need 800 seperate queries or a single query to be executed. But for sure this approach will solve your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine all the sql statements into 1 long string by keeping semi-colon (;) between each then send everything at once

```
foreach($tables as $table){
  $sql .= 'UPDATE `table` SET `order` = '$i' WHERE `id` ='.$table['id'].';';
  $i++;
}
mysqli_multi_query($sql); //do this after loop completes
```

Or did I misunderstand your request?

Comment: Your approach still has the loop, which will make multiple requests

Comment: For Mysql, it's the same than the query in the loop. When there's 500 rows to change, I'm not sure that Mysql love it..

Comment: This looks like a possible SQL injection opportunity - can this be done with bound variables instead?